# Unable to use reanimated-bottom-sheet in React-Native

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I install [**reanimated-bottom-sheet**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reanimated-bottom-sheet) in my react native project but I faced with this error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'InnerNativeModule.installCoreFunctions')  ERROR  Invariant Violation:
> Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling
> runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that t frequent
> cause of the error is that the application entry file path is
> incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

this is my code :

```
import BottomSheet from 'reanimated-bottom-sheet';

const renderContent = () => (
    <View
        style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            padding: 16,
            height: 450,
        }}
    >
        <Text>Swipe down to close</Text>
    </View>
);

const sheetRef = React.useRef(null);

return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'papayawhip',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
            }}
        >
            <Button
                title="Open Bottom Sheet"
                onPress={() => sheetRef.current.snapTo(1)}
            />
        </View>
        <BottomSheet
            ref={sheetRef}
            snapPoints={[450, 300, 0]}
            borderRadius={10}
            renderContent={renderContent}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>
);
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure but can you see the package in "package.json"? In that case it sometimes work to fix dependency errors by just removing the folder "node_modules" and then enter npm_install again (so the dependencies that are in package.json gets reinstalled) Then re-open your code editor!

Comment: I do your recommendation but it does not work

Answer (score 3):

Current library that you have used will not work with latest `react-native-reanimated` version.

You have to use react-native-reanimated version 1.x with that.

Or you can use this updated library https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet